# C# Temperature Converter

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a temperature converter and everything is working great.

```
    private void hsbTemperature_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        TempFah = hsbTemperature.Value;
        txtCelsius.Text = Convert.ToString(TempFah);
        TempCel = Convert.ToInt32((TempFah - 32) * 5 / 9);
        txtFahrenheit.Text = TempCel.ToString();
    }

    private void hsbTemperature_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TempFah = hsbTemperature.Value;
        txtCelsius.Text = Convert.ToString(TempFah);
        TempCel = Convert.ToInt32((TempFah - 32) * 5 / 9);
        txtFahrenheit.Text = TempCel.ToString();
    }
}
```

However, when i try to change the value for the Fahrenheit textbox,the value of Celsius's textbox does not change and vise-versa. The values for both of the textboxes only change when i move the scrollbar.

So what i require is that when i change the value for my Fahrenheit i want the value for Celsius to also change and vise-versa.

Please help, Thank You.

Comment: Take a look at what events are available on textbox control, where you can wireup your functions.

Comment: Well, you are changing the values only when you change the scroll value, how do you expect to change when you modify the textboxes if you don't handle any event on them?

Comment: Just be careful: if you hook the `TextChanged` event of `txtFahrenheit` to change the text of `txtCelsius`, and you also have code in the `TextChanged` event of `txtCelsius` to change the text of `txtFahrenheit`, then you'll hit an infinite loop and your program will hang.

Comment: Easy way to avoid the infinite loop is just do an if check at the start to see if you need to change. If the value is already correct then just return. Then you'll short circuit the infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

It looks like you already have these class level properties defined:

```
private int TempFah;
private int TempCel;
```

Also, you don't need to put any code in the `Scroll` event. `ValueChanged` is really what we care about, and it will get called right after `Scroll` anyway.

```
private void hsbTemperature_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    // Don't use this method when you really care about the value
}
```

So that we don't end up in any infinite loops of property change events triggering each other, I created a private `bool` variable to keep track of whether we are updating the text fields programmatically or not (as opposed to the user doing it). If this is set to true, then we don't need to process any code in the change events because the `UpdateTempFields` method (coming up) is already doing it.

```
private bool programIsUpdatingProperties = false;
```

Just to help separate out the code into re-usable parts, we can create a separate function to get the Celsius value from a Fahrenheit value. And while we're at it, make one that does the opposite:

```
private int GetCelciusValue(int fahrenheitValue)
{
    return (fahrenheitValue - 32) * 5 / 9;
}

private int GetFahrenheitValue(int celsiusValue)
{
    return celsiusValue * 9 / 5 + 32;
}
```

Now it's time to create the `UpdateTempFields` method which, given a Fahrenheit temperature, knows how to update all the control values on the form.

One trick to ensure that we don't over-set the `hsbTemperature.Value` (the user could enter one that's too big or small) is to use the smallest of either the `hsbTemperature.Maximum` or the number, and to ensure we don't under-set it, we get the maximum value of either the `hsbTemperature.Minimum` or the number. This is done below using `Math.Max` and `Math.Min` below:

```
private void UpdateTempFields(int newFahrenheitTemp)
{
    // Let the rest of the code know this is us, not the user
    programIsUpdatingProperties = true;

    TempFah = newFahrenheitTemp;
    TempCel = GetCelciusValue(TempFah);

    txtCelsius.Text = TempCel.ToString();
    txtFahrenheit.Text = TempFah.ToString();

    // Ensure we don't try to set the scroll bar to a value it can't handle
    hsbTemperature.Value =
        Math.Max(hsbTemperature.Minimum,
            Math.Min(hsbTemperature.Maximum, TempFah));

    // Carry on as normal now...
    programIsUpdatingProperties = false;
}
```

Now, in the change events for our controls, all we have to do is call the `UpdateTempFields()` method with a Fahrenheit value, and it will take care of the rest. But we only want to do this if the user is the one changing the value, so check our flag first:

```
private void txtFahrenheit_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!programIsUpdatingProperties)
    {
        int fahrValue;
        // Use int.TryParse to ensure it's a valid integer (if it's not, do nothing)
        if (int.TryParse(txtFahrenheit.Text, out fahrValue))
        {
            UpdateTempFields(fahrValue);
        }
    }
}

private void txtCelsius_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!programIsUpdatingProperties)
    {
        int celsiusValue;
        // Use int.TryParse to ensure it's a valid integer (if it's not, do nothing)
        if (int.TryParse(txtCelsius.Text, out celsiusValue))
        {
            // Convert celcius to fahrenheit first
            var fahrValue = GetFahrenheitValue(celsiusValue);
            UpdateTempFields(fahrValue);
        }
    }
}

private void hsbTemperature_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!programIsUpdatingProperties)
    {
        UpdateTempFields(hsbTemperature.Value);
    }
}
```